# How to translate "I took two pictures"?

Tags: translation, verbs

On [Tatoeba](http://tatoeba.org/epo/sentences/show/1191068) I found these translations for "Please don't take pictures here":

> *Bonvolu ne fotografi ĉi tie.*
>
> *Bonvolu ne foti ĉi tie.*
>
> *Bonvolu ne fari fotojn ĉi tie.*
>
> *Bonvolu ne preni fotojn.*

Can "I took two pictures" be translated to *"mi faris du fotojn"* and *"mi prenis du fotojn"*?

*"Fari foton"* is more frequent than *"preni foton"* on Tatoeba, but I didn't find both in dictionaries and on [Tekstaro](http://tekstaro.com/). Are there examples of use in the literature?

Comment: I don't advise using Tatoeba for finding example sentences.

Comment: @Vanege Why not?

Comment: @grooveplex Because all good dictionnaries (such as PIV/Vortaro.net and Reta Vortaro) already provide enough exemple sentences from reputable source, while sentences from Tatoeba are often translated from English from anonymous people. Because of that, there are significantly more errors. Also, there is tekstaro.com for searching into a Esperanto corpus.

Comment: As a corpus maintainer of Tatoeba, i'd like to react ;-) Yes, many sentences are added by beginners or by „eternaj komencantoj” but we try to check every sentence and correct as soon as possible. You might also want to check the corpus of Monato (www.monato.net, search engine on the left of the page) which has modern every day language.

Comment: @PaŭlPeeraerts , please write an answer, not just a comment. I was looking for examples, and now I found it on the [Monato's site](http://www.esperanto.be/fel/mon/red/fotoj.php), as you suggested.

Answer (score 8):

Correct me if I’m wrong but I think *preni* is wrong in this context. Just because English uses *take* for *pictures* doesn’t mean Esperanto must too. I see no examples of such use on [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#preni) and the many definitions of *preni* there seem to convince me that this use is wrong.

I believe

> preni fotojn

would actually mean you took the pictures from somewhere (in order to move them to a different place) or just acquired them, and not that you *made* them, which would be *fari*.

So,

> **fari**

Comment: I just edited my answer about this issue.

Comment: I don't know if "preni fotojn" is wrong, but in practice I think I have heard only "fari fotojn" anyway.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is

> Mi fotis dufoje.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use Mi prenis du fotojn, but Mi faris du fotojn is definitely correct too, or even more correct and easy to understand by anyone. Preni would literally not be correct, but Zamenhof said that all words can be used both in concrete and abstract sense, and as most languages use this the same way, it's at least permittable.